# The Buttons Mixed up

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

ID LIKE TO START OFF BY SAYING I AM A STUDENT AND I AM CURRENTLY LEARNING SWIFT. I DON'T HAVE A 100% UNDERSTANDING.

Hey, so, my buttons keep getting mixed up with the code. I tell on button to display a message on a label when its clicked, but it displays something else that I told another button to do. I don't know how to explain the problem that well, sorry.

I have the top button (there's four total) display "You Are Correct!" and also have a button appear, written in code but when I press the button, when I run the app, it displays "You Are Wrong!", which is what all the other buttons are supposed to say.

Its a quiz game with Music related terms.

I've tried changing the tags for the buttons (1-4) and that didn't work, I also tried just disconnecting them and deleting them off the story board and adding everything back on, but that also didn't work.

```
import UIKit

class QuizVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!




@IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var button4: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var Next: UIButton!

var CorrectAnswer = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    RandomQuestions()
}


func RandomQuestions() {
    var RandomNumber = arc4random() % 5
    var RandomQuestion = arc4random() % 4
    RandomQuestion += 1
    RandomNumber += 1
    Next.isHidden = true

    switch(RandomNumber) {

    case 1:
        if RandomQuestion == UInt32(1) {
            questionLabel.text = "What is the tail end of a piece of music?"
            button1.setTitle("Coda", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Da Capo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Forte", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Largo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "1"
        } else if RandomQuestion == UInt32(2) {
            questionLabel.text = "What is the tail end of a piece of music?"
            button1.setTitle("Da Capo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Largo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Coda", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Forte", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "3"
        } else if RandomQuestion == UInt32(3) {
            questionLabel.text = "What is the tail end of a piece of music?"
            button1.setTitle("Largo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Da Capo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Forte", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Coda", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "4"
        } else {
            questionLabel.text = "What is the tail end of a piece of music?"
            button1.setTitle("Largo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Coda", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Forte", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Da Capo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "2"
        }
        break
    case 2:
        if RandomQuestion == UInt32(1) {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Majestically?"
            button1.setTitle("Lunga", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Dolce", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Maestoso", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Molto", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "3"
        } else if RandomQuestion == UInt32(2) {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Majestically?"
            button1.setTitle("Dolce", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Lunga", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Molto", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Maestoso", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "4"
        } else if RandomQuestion == UInt32(3) {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Majestically?"
            button1.setTitle("Molto", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Maestoso", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Lunga", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Dolce", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "2"
        } else {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Majestically?"
            button1.setTitle("Maestoso", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Dolce", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Lunga", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Molto", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "1"
        }
        break
    case 3:
        if RandomQuestion == UInt32(1) {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Time/Speed?"
            button1.setTitle("Largo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Soli", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Tenuto", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Tempo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "4"
        } else if RandomQuestion == UInt32(2) {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Time/Speed?"
            button1.setTitle("Soli", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Tenuto", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Tempo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Largo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "3"
        } else if RandomQuestion == UInt32(3) {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Time/Speed?"
            button1.setTitle("Tempo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Largo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Soli", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Tenuto", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "1"
        } else {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Time/Speed?"
            button1.setTitle("Largo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Tempo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Tenuto", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Soli", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "2"
        }
        break
    case 4:
        if RandomQuestion == UInt32(1) {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Softly"
            button1.setTitle("Piano", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Forte", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Segno", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Tacet", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "1"
        } else if RandomQuestion == UInt32(2) {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Softly"
            button1.setTitle("Forte", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Tacet", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Piano", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Segno", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "3"
        } else if RandomQuestion == UInt32(3) {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Softly"
            button1.setTitle("Tacet", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Segno", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Forte", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Piano", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "4"
        } else {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Softly"
            button1.setTitle("Forte", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Piano", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Segno", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Tacet", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "2"
        }
        break
    case 5:
        if RandomQuestion == UInt32(1) {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Really Fast?"
            button1.setTitle("Staccato", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Fermata", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Presto", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Mezzo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "3"
        } else if RandomQuestion == UInt32(2) {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Really Fast?"
            button1.setTitle("Fermata", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Presto", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Staccato", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Mezzo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "2"
        } else if RandomQuestion == UInt32(3) {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Really Fast?"
            button1.setTitle("Fermata", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Mezzo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Staccato", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Presto", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "4"
        } else {
            questionLabel.text = "Another name for Really Fast?"
            button1.setTitle("Presto", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button2.setTitle("Mezzo", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button3.setTitle("Staccato", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            button4.setTitle("Fermata", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            CorrectAnswer = "1"
        }
    default:

        break
    }
}




@IBAction func NextAction(_ sender: Any) {
    RandomQuestions()
    answerLabel.text = ""
}


@IBAction func button1Action(_ sender: Any) {
    if (CorrectAnswer == "1"){
        answerLabel.text = "You Are Correct!"
        Next.isHidden = false
    } else {
        answerLabel.text = "You Are Wrong!"
        Next.isHidden = true
    }
}

@IBAction func button2Action(_ sender: Any) {
    if (CorrectAnswer == "2"){
        answerLabel.text = "You Are Correct!"
        Next.isHidden = false
    } else {
        answerLabel.text = "You Are Wrong!"
        Next.isHidden = true
    }
}

@IBAction func button3Action(_ sender: Any) {
    if (CorrectAnswer == "3"){
        answerLabel.text = "You Are Correct!"
        Next.isHidden = false
    } else {
        answerLabel.text = "You Are Wrong!"
        Next.isHidden = true
    }
}

@IBAction func button4Action(_ sender: Any) {
    if (CorrectAnswer == "4"){
        answerLabel.text = "You Are Correct!"
        Next.isHidden = false
    } else {
        answerLabel.text = "You Are Wrong!"
        Next.isHidden = true
    }
}

}
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?
I've looked through the code and didn't see any errors but I might just be too inexperienced to actually notice the real errors.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of duplication in your code.  You can share an @IBAction for all of your answer buttons if you make use of the button `tag`.  Also, if you `shuffle()` the answers, you can eliminate more duplicated code.

Your mix up in the buttons might have been that you had buttons accidentally connected to multiple `@IBAction`s. That can happen if you copy a button in the Storyboard after it has a connection. Then adding a second connection caused the button to call two `@IBAction`s. This updated code is much more straightforward and should eliminate such a mixup.

```
import UIKit

// The format of the data is ["Question", "correct answer", "wrong answer 1", "wrong answer 2",
// "wrong answer 3"].  The answers will be shuffled after a random question has been chosen.
let quizData: [[String]] = [
    ["What is the tail end of a piece of music?", "Coda", "Da Capo", "Forte", "Largo"],
    ["Another name for Majestically?", "Maestoso", "Dolce", "Lunga", "Molto"],
    ["Another name for Time/Speed?", "Tempo", "Largo", "Soli", "Tenuto"],
    ["Another name for Softly", "Piano", "Forte", "Segno", "Tacet"],
    ["Another name for Really Fast?", "Presto","Mezzo", "Staccato", "Fermata"]
]

class QuizVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button4: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!

    var correctAnswer = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set tag for each button.  This could also be done in Storyboard
        for (idx, button) in [button1, button2, button3, button4].enumerated() {
            button?.tag = idx + 1
        }
        randomQuestions()
    }

    func randomQuestions() {
        // Pick a random question
        let questionData = quizData.randomElement()
        let rightAnswer = questionData[1]

        // Shuffle the answers
        let randomAnswers = questionData.dropFirst().shuffled()

        // Find out where the correct answer ended up
        correctAnswer = randomAnswers.firstIndex(of: rightAnswer)! + 1

        questionLabel.text = questionData[0]
        for (idx, button) in [button1, button2, button3, button4].enumerated() {
            button?.setTitle(randomAnswers[idx], for: .normal)
        }

        nextButton.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func nextAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        randomQuestions()
        answerLabel.text = ""
    }

    // Connect buttons 1 through 4 to this action
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if correctAnswer == sender.tag {
            answerLabel.text = "You Are Correct!"
            nextButton.isHidden = false
        } else {
            answerLabel.text = "You Are Wrong!"
            nextButton.isHidden = true
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Would that fix the mix up in the buttons?

Comment: Your mix up in the buttons might have been that you had buttons accidentally connected to multiple `@IBAction`s.  That can happen if you copy a button in the Storyboard after it has a connection.  Then adding a second connection caused the button to call two `@IBAction`s.  This is much more straightforward and should eliminate such a mixup.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the help :) Fixing it soon.